# Setting color to line layer using VBA in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcobjects, symbology, vba

I am getting the compile error at pcolor.RGB.

I want to add a color to the line feature.

How to modify the code?

```
Public Sub surya()

Dim pmxdoc As IMxDocument
Dim pstylegallery As IStyleGallery
Dim pEnustylegalleryItem As IEnumStyleGalleryItem
Dim pstylegalleryItem As IStyleGalleryItem

Dim plinesymbol As ILineSymbol
Dim pcolor As IColorSymbol


Dim pmap As IMap
Dim player As ILayer
Dim pFealayer As IFeatureLayer
Dim pgeofealayer As IGeoFeatureLayer

Dim psimplerender As ISimpleRenderer

Set pmxdoc = Application.Document
Set pstylegallery = pmxdoc.StyleGallery
Set pEnustylegalleryItem = pstylegallery.Items("Line symbols", "ESRI.Style", "Dashed")
Set pstylegalleryItem = pEnustylegalleryItem.Next

Set plinesymbol = pstylegalleryItem.Item
plinesymbol.Width = 5#
plinesymbol.Color = pcolor.Color


Set psimplerender = New SimpleRenderer
Set psimplerender.Symbol = plinesymbol


Set pmap = pmxdoc.FocusMap
Set player = pmap.Layer(0)
Set pgeofealayer = player
Set pgeofealayer.Renderer = psimplerender

pmxdoc.UpdateContents
pmxdoc.ActiveView.Refresh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

pcolor shouldn't be an [IColorSymbol](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000002w1000000) (which doesn't have Color as a property) it should be an [IColor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000000mm000000) (I prefer [IRgbColor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000002nz000000) cast to IColor when needed) as [ILineSymbol.Color](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001w000001q4000000) is an IColor object. I suspect though that the problem is that pcolor isn't intialized:

```
Dim pcolor As IRgbColor
set pcolor = New RgbColorClass()
pcolor.Red = 255 ' make it red

' then later
plinesymbol.Color = pcolor ' IRgbColor is a CoClass that implements IColor
```

Whether you're using IColor, IRgbColor, IColorSymbol or other objects like IGeometry when you start with a new one you must initialize it to a new object to open up some memory and set the defaults otherwise the variable is pointing to nothing and you simply can't use it.